# Valores de um Enum só podem ser inteiros?

Tags: c#, enums

Estudando C#, me deparei com uma situação, quero receber um valor (*string*) pelo console. E então compara-lo com o valor de um *enum*. Por exemplo:

```
[Serializable]
public enum Command
{
    Exit            = "/exit",
    SendMessage     = "/msg",
    WhoIs           = "/whois"
}
```

E então, quero comparar o valor e executar as devidas ações:

```
switch(cmd)
    case Command.Exit:
    /* executa ações necessárias */
```

Mas está dando problema, pois a variável `cmd` é uma *string* e estou comparando um *enum*. É possível utilizar *enum* para isso? Como fazer? Tem alguma alternativa melhor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) representa um conjunto(enumeração) de constantes.
Cada enumeração tem associado a ela um tipo inteiro, excepto `char`, o tipo por defeito é `int`.
Os tipos permitidos são `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` ou `ulong`.

O tipo é atribuído à enumeração da seguinte forma:

```
public enum : long Command
{
}
```

O primeiro valor da enumeração recebe, por defeito, o valor `0`, o valor é depois incrementado em 1 e atribuído à constante seguinte, o processo é repetido para todas as constantes.

Pegando no seu exemplo

```
public enum Command
{
    Exit,
    SendMessage,
    WhoIs
}
```

cada constante recebe os seguintes valores:

`Exit = 0`, `SendMessage = 1` e `WhoIs = 2`

Os valores atribuídos por defeito podem ser substituídos usando *inicializadores*:

```
public enum Command
{
    Exit = 1,
    SendMessage,
    WhoIs = 4
}
```

Os *inicializadores*, além de atribuírem um valor à constante, inicializam a sequência dos valores das constantes seguintes:

`Exit = 1`, `SendMessage = 2` e `WhoIs = 4`

Dito isto e respondendo à sua pergunta os valores das constantes de um *enum* só podem ser do tipo inteiro.

No entanto, recorrendo ao uso de [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx), podemos fazer o que você pretende.

Primeiro escrevemos uma classe para representar esse atributo, essa classe herda de *Attribute*:

```
public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    //Propriedade que recebe a string que irá ser atribuída à constante
    public string StringValue { get; protected set; }

    //No construtor inicializa-se a propriedade
    public StringValueAttribute(string value)
    {
        StringValue = value;
    }
}
```

Para obter o valor do atributo recorremos à *Reflection*.
Para facilitar as coisas vamos criar o código como um método de extensão.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetStringValue(this Enum value)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

        var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

        var stringvalue = attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].StringValue : value.ToString();
        return stringvalue;
    }
}
```

**Forma de usar**

Primeiro associam-se os atributos aos elementos do *enum*

```
public enum Command
{
    [StringValue("/exit")]
    Exit,
    [StringValue("/msg")]
    SendMessage,
    [StringValue("/whois")]
    WhoIs
}
```

depois, para obter a string, usa-se o método `GetStringValue()`.
Não poderá usar `switch` por isso use `else if`:

```
if(cmd == Command.Exit.GetStringValue())
{ 
    ......
    ......         
}
else if(cmd == Command.SendMessage.GetStringValue())
{
    ......
    ......         
}
else if(cmd == Command.WhoIs.GetStringValue())
{
    ......
    ......         
}    
....
.....
```

<sub>***Nota:*** Se não tiver sido associado nenhum atributo é retornado o nome da constante</sub>

<sub>***Créditos:*** A classe *GetStringValue* foi escrita/adaptada recorrendo a informação existente na *net*. Infelizmente não me recordo onde.</sub>

Comment: Opa ramaral, tentei aplicar esse método, mas o VS2013 aponta um erro de que é esperado um valor constante. :/

Comment: Onde? Em que linha?

Comment: Sobre o valor do case: `case Command.Exit.GetStringValue():`

Comment: Tem razão não dá para ser utilizado no `switch`. Utilize `if()..else if()`

Comment: Gostei dessa implementação @ramaral. Me ajudou demais.

Answer (score 4):

Conforme a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) os únicos tipos aceitos pelo `Enum` são:

`byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` e `ulong`

Eu não uso muito C#, mas nas demais linguagens de programação, se eu não estiver enganado, o uso do `Enum` seria semelhante a varias constantes numéricas com um *namespace* (é só uma explicação para compreensão, não é bem isso) com valores numéricos mas representados por "textos", como o `Exit` que você criou.

A ideia é receber "números" que serão comparados com a estrutura do ENUM. Podem haver mais usos para isto, mas o uso básico é sempre usar a estrutura do ENUM para se guiar, sem esquecer o significado daquele numero, por exemplo:

```
enviaSinal(Command.Exit);
```

Este método imaginário terá o `switch` que irá comparar o comando enviado.

Agora se o que você quer é usar "argumentos" passados em uma linha de comando no teu software, você pode usar um vetor, seria algo como:

```
IDictionary<string, string> Commands = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["Exit"]        = "/exit";
dict["SendMessage"] = "/msg";
dict["WhoIs"]       = "/whois";
```

Você também pode criar uma classe com variáveis estáticas (eu realmente não sei se este é o melhor caminho):

```
class Commands
{
    static readonly string Exit        = "/exit";
    static readonly string SendMessage = "/msg";
    static readonly string WhoIs       = "/whois";
}
```

Note que as variáveis são somente-leitura.