# Como recuperar a descrição de um enumerador?

Tags: c#, enums

Tenho o seguinte enumerador

```
public enum MeuEnumerador
{
    [Description("Descrição do item do enumerador")]
    Enumerador1 = 1,
    [Description("Outra descrição")]
    Enumerador2 = 2
}
```

Como faço para obter o valor que está na `Description`do enumerador?

Comment: Relacionado [Valores de um Enum só podem ser inteiros](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71358/2541)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução criando as seguintes extensões para o tipo `Enum`

```
public static T ObterAtributoDoTipo<T>(this Enum valorEnum) where T : System.Attribute
{
    var type = valorEnum.GetType();
    var memInfo = type.GetMember(valorEnum.ToString());
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
    return (attributes.Length > 0) ? (T)attributes[0] : null;
}

public static string ObterDescricao(this Enum valorEnum)
{
    return valorEnum.ObterAtributoDoTipo<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;
}
```

Onde a extensão `ObterAtributoDoTipo<T>` irá me retornar o atributo que for solicitado, nesse caso o `Description`. Exemplo de uso:

```
var meuEnumerador = MeuEnumerador.Enumerador1;
Attribute atributo = meuEnumerador.ObterAtributoDoTipo<DescriptionAttribute>();
```

E a extensão `ObterDescrição` irá me retornar de fato a `Description`e para isso ela usa a outra extensão para buscar o atributo. Exemplo de uso:

```
var meuEnumerador = MeuEnumerador.Enumerador1;
string descricao = meuEnumerador.ObterDescricao();
```

Procurei em vários lugares sobre como fazer, e essa foi a melhor solução que encontrei, caso alguém saiba outras formas de fazer isso, compartilhe nas repostas.

Answer (score 0):

é só usar o getDescription:

```
var teste = MeuEnumerador.GetDescription();
```