# Dúvida ao declarar enum com string

Tags: c#, enums

numDeclarar um enum tipo string, assim:

```
public enum SEXO
{
    M = "Masculino",
    F = "Feminino"
}
```

Como eu faço para ter um enum semelhante ao preposto acima. Dessa forma dar erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Você não pode, enums são números, não strings.

Comment: @jbueno, eu sei disso, por isso eu perguntei como eu faço para ter um enum semelhante ao obtido no post.

Comment: Quando preciso algo assim, eu uso a `Description` da `enum`. Veja nessa pergunta [Como recuperar a descrição de um enumerador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99497/como-recuperar-a-descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-enumerador) como faço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode, ao menos não diretamente da forma que está tentando fazer na pergunta.

Você pode conseguir um efeito semelhante usando `extensions`, veja o exemplo

```
public static string GetStringValue(this Enum value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();

    var fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

    var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

    var stringvalue = attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].StringValue : value.ToString();
    return stringvalue;
}

public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string StringValue { get; protected set; }

    public StringValueAttribute(string value)
    {
        StringValue = value;
    }
}
```

Declaração do enum

```
public enum Sexo
{
    [StringValue("Masculino")]
    M = 1,    
    [StringValue("Feminino")]
    F = 2
}
```

**Uso**

```
string descrEnum = Sexo.M.GetStringValue();
```

---

Eu vagamente lembrava que esse código tinha saído daqui do SOpt, agora pouco encontrei [ele nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71376/18246).